# How do I register Pepper Plugins with QWebEngine?

Tags: plugins, google-nativeclient, qtwebengine

I am trying to use the Pepper Plugin API with a QWebEngine-based browser. (It is probably going to be an implementation along the lines of Qt's browser examples "demobrowser" or "quicknanaobrowser".)

I am able to get the getting started examples for [Google's Native Client Plugins](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) to work with my copy of Google's Chrome Browser. However with my own browser, the plugins refuse to load.

I have found [Qt's instructions about Pepper Plugin API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pepper-plugin-api) which tells me besides setting *QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled* to *true* (which my code does) that ...

> ... the plugins must be loaded manually using the Chromium command line syntax with the --register-pepper-plugins argument ...

My question is now, since it is a QWebEngine Application, my code doesn't call Chrome explicitly (instead an instance of QtWebEngineProcess.exe is launched implicitly). How would I specify the *--register-pepper-plugins* instead?

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tried working through the examples but could only get them to start working on chome. With a QWebEngine browser I never got very far. I eventually ran out of time and had to come up with a workaround.

Comment: what was the work around?

Comment: Well, the problem I was trying to solve was to display PDFs in the browser. The original approach was to use an EMBED element with the PDF path  as source attribute. (Which I dind't get to work)

The workaround I ended up using was to use an IFRAME  and  [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) instead. THe IFRAME was supplied with the correct URL to have PDF.js display the document according to the PDF.js documentation) 

Unfortunately I can't go into too much detail here since I am not on my work machine. So I hope you get the idea.

Comment: sure thanks . I Have another solution .I installed the new  flash player from adobe 's website and it worked automatically .Hope this helps you too